# Altium deisgner: drawing 4x10k resistor

Tags: resistors, schematics, altium

I am drawing a schematics in Altium Designer. Based on an old design, there is 4*10k resistor as shown in the figure below. It is actually one component (one Part No in the library) with 4 different parts. So the first resistor is R12A, the second one is R12B, R12C and R12D.

I want to draw this 4x10k resistor in my new design. I found its Part No in the library. Later, I fixed part number to each one. So the first one is 1/4, the second is 2/4 and so on. The problem is coming when I annotate the schematics. Each resistor get a unique designator number instead of one designator number with different parts!!

[image]

To summarize my problem:

1)I need one Designator number with four different parts (R12A, R12A, R12C, R12D).
2)when I annotate the schematics, it became like (R12, R13, R14, R15)

Any Tips ?!

Comment: Custom libraries are definitely the way to go. I recommend NEVER using existing library parts or third-party library parts. It leads to very inconsistent styles and they're more difficult to work with (if you want to make a resistor network, for example).

Comment: can't understand what is the meaning by custom library ?

Comment: You create your own library. Which word don't you understand? "Custom" or "Library"? Perhaps this video I made will help -- It explains how to create your own custom library for components: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-kyY25CGJtM

Comment: I really liked this video :), it will help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I use for this situation (custom part):

[image]

There is one part designator (it's one part). I prefer to show the pin numbers.

It's also possible to create a part with sections A, B, C, D, or to have two options for the same type of device (so you can use the most appropriate symbol for a given situation).

To create individual sections, you create a part that looks like a single resistor in the shape of your choice. Then select the part in SCH Library and use Tools->New Part (**not** New Component) several times and you'll have this:

[image]

Then select each section and edit the symbol and pins to agree with the physical part. More in [this](http://wiki.altium.com/download/temp/pdfexport-20160322-220316-1017-358067/ADOH-CreatingLibraryComponents-220316-1017-358068.pdf) tutorial.

The default designator for the above situation is R?A. to R?D, as you said you want, but you may prefer to alter that if you are doing multiple channel design.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion I think you have to make your own custom symbol/component. So once you create your own component you can add it to the catalogue and use it as a single component with a single designator. And also since each resistor is connected to some other terminal on the PCB therefore it gives different part numbers for each so that it recognizes which resistor is connected where. Or else it wont be able to identify them uniquely. So try to make a custom component there is a possibility that it might give a single designator.